# How to use Firebase admin SDK with google cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to generate an email sign in link using the `admin.auth().generateSignInWithEmailLink` method provided by the Firebase Admin SDK. I'm attempting to do this within a Google cloud function.

Here is my `index.js` file (All packaged are installed):

```
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.sendLoginLink = function(req, res) {
  cors(req, res, () => {

    const actionCodeSettings = {
      url: 'http://localhost:8083/account/dashboard/?email=' + req.body.email,
      handleCodeInApp: true
    };

    admin.auth().generateSignInWithEmailLink(req.body.email, actionCodeSettings)
      .then((link) => {
                console.log(link)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res.status(500)
      });
  });
};
```

I've passed an email from my front-end app to the cloud function which works, the actionCodeSettings also output correctly, but i'm not able to make it past the first line in the `generateSignInWithEmailLink()` when debugging.

Anyone know why?

Comment: " i'm not able to make it past the first line" I'm not sure I understand what this means.  What happens when you run this code? And what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Sorry wasn't too clear. I had meant that if I was to put a console.log statement in the code e.g. console.log(link) it would not fire.

I expect the code to take the email and actioncodesettings parameter, and then produce a link.

Comment: That depends on whether the value of `req.body.email` is correct. But it should either call your `then` handler with a link, or the `catch` handler with an error. Are you saying neither is called? If not, what is showing in the logs in the Firebase console for this function invocation?

Comment: Also: if you run the same `admin.auth().generateSignInWithEmailLink(req.body.email, actionCodeSettings)` in a local Node.js script, do you have the same problem. If so, the problem is not related to Cloud Functions, which will make it easier to help.

Comment: Hey Frank, turns out the issue was actually with the admin SDK not initializing properly, but thanks for your help.